# keras.utils.plot_model() draws an incorrect structure of a model with custom layers names

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've created a model consisting of three different TextVectorization layers, five different self-made pre-trained models, and a small Dense MLP on the output.  A graph of the model by the keras.utils.plot_model() with default names is shown here (and has been drawn as expected).

[image]

Then I decided to rename layers in the model to improve clarity, and I employed this simple code:

```
names = ['Input', 
         'VectorizationType1', 'VectorizationType2','VectorizationType3', 
         'MLP16mhot', 'MLP32emb8', 'LSTM32', 'Conv1D32', 'Transf2H',
         'Concatenation',
         'MLP-Analytical',
         'Output']

for new_name, layer in zip(names, ensemble.layers):
     layer._name = new_name
```

ensemble.summary() shows all the things pretty fine:

[image]

However, the output of the keras.utils.plot_model() changed to drawing just a linear structure of building blocks.

[image]

Is there a way to get the right structure drawing in this case, and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add the image directly or code block, not link? Then I can help you.

Comment: @HSL Thank you for the help in advance. I’ve added images directly in the question.

Comment: Hi @Pavlo Yan, Can you please share the model definition code to replicate the error.

Comment: @TFers2, if it is acceptable for you, please use the link to Google Colab Notebook with the reproduced issue and all the code and data (except the code of the embedded models) - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rrYTsPZ1VhU6k0MhOltlL1DabVyzZ4fE?usp=sharing